# SQL Server Multiple Likes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an unusual question that seems simple but has me stumped in a SQL Server stored procedure.

I have 2 tables as described below.

**tblMaster**

```
ID, CommitDate, SubUser, OrigFileName
```

Sample data

```
ID   CommitDate   SubUser   OrigFileName
----------------------------------------
1    2014-10-07   Test1     Test1.pdf
2    2014-10-08   Test2     Test2.pdf
3    2014-10-09   Test3     Test3.pdf
```

The above table is basically the header table that tracks the committed files. In addition to this, we have a details table with the following structure.

**tblIndex**

```
ID, FileID (Linking column to the header row described above), Word
```

Sample data:

```
 1. 1, 1, Oil
 2. 2, 1, oil
 3. 3, 2, oil
 4. 4, 2, tank
 5. 5, 3, tank
```

The above rows represent the words that we want to search on and if a certain criteria matches return the corresponding filename/header row ID.  What I would love to figure out to do is if I do a search for

1. One word (i.e. "oil"), then the system should respond with all the files that meet the criteria (easiest case and figured out)
2. If more than one word is searched for (i.e. "oil" and "tank"), then we should only see the second file since it is the only one that has both oil and tank as its key words.

   - Tried using a LIKE "%oil%" AND LIKE "%tank%" and that resulted in no rows being created since one value can't be both oil and tank.
   - Tried doing a LIKE "%oil%" OR LIKE "%tank%" but I get files 1, 2, and 3 since the OR is inclusive of all the other rows.
   - One last thing, I recognize I could just do a search for the first term and then save the results into a temp table and then search for the second term in that second table and I will get what I am looking for.  The problem with that is that I don't exactly know how many items will be searched for.  I don't want to have to create a structure where I am constantly having to store data into another temp table if someone does a search for 6 "keywords".

Any help/ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ! slightly differing from the previous answer

```
SELECT distinct FileID,COUNT(distinct t.word)  FROM tblIndex t
WHERE t.Word LIKE '%oil%' OR t.Word LIKE '%tank%'
GROUP BY FileID 
HAVING COUNT(distinct t.word) > 1
```

Comment: this worked great.  I would like to ask another question if possible.  If I have more than 2 words to search for "big oil tank" does the HAVING COUNT increase to > 2 as well?

Comment: Yes it does. It is the number of distinct words that need to be matched, in your example more than 2, hence >2.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option would be to do something like this :

```
SELECT FileID
FROM tblIndex t
WHERE t.Word LIKE '%oil%' OR t.Word LIKE '%tank%'
GROUP BY FileID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This assume you do not have duplicate in your tblIndex.

I'm also unsure whether you really need the like or not. According to your sample data you don't, a basic comparison would be way more efficient and would avoid possible collisions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have duplicated rows in the index.  The reason being that this index represents all the instances of a particular word in a file.  So I don't have any idea how many times the word "oil" will appears in a file.  Also, you are right that LIKE is not necessary if I want an exact match. I just wanted to include what I had tried.